# Cleaner Way to Change Dictionary Structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, data-structures

I have the following object type in python, there are several entries in the data-object just like the one below.

```
>                                                         G1  \
jobname                                    
x        [3.3935e-06, 6.099100000000001e-06, 8.8048e-06...   
y        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14...   
yerr     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   
xfit     [3.3935e-06, 4.0631e-06, 4.7327000000000004e-0...   
yfit     [-0.0215695613, -0.0215695613, -0.0215695613, ...   
xlabel                                      Pulse Time (s)   
ylabel                                          Avg Counts   
params   [-3.6475000000000002e-06, -0.0026722969, -3.20...   
x0                                                  -374.2   
x0_err                                           1.124e+07
```

I have been able to change the structure with the following code but I want to be able to do this is a cleaner way. I tried list comprehension, but that doesn't seem to be any cleaner. I also dont want to create all of the empyy lists before initializing the class.

```
class change_dataframe(): 
    
    def flatten(l):
        return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]


    def process_data(data, zones:list): 

        for zone in zones: 
            for x in df[zone]['x']:
                zone_list.append(zone)
            xdata_append.append(df[zone]['x'])
            ydata_append.append(df[zone]['y'])
            xfit_append.append(df[zone]['xfit'])
            yfit_append.append(df[zone]['yfit'])

        xdata = flatten(xdata_append)
        ydata = flatten(ydata_append)
        xfit = flatten(xfit_append)
        yfit = flatten(yfit_append)
        
        data = pd.DataFrame({'zones':zone_list,'x':xdata, 'y':ydata})
        fit_data = pd.DataFrame({'xfit':xfit, 'yfit':yfit})

        return fit_data, data
        
                              
# x_data, y_data = process_data(df,zones)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xdata_append = []
    xfit_append = []
    ydata_append = []
    yfit_append = []
    
    zone_list = []
    zones = ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5']
    data = change_dataframe.process_data(df,zones)
    print(data)
# zones_list = flatten(zones_append)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your `df` so we can reproduce what your `process_data` function is doing? if you can paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question as formatted text, that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
    def process_data(data, zones:list):
```

but Author's Intent was apparently

```
    def process_data(df, zones:list):
```

---

Are we writing class methods, which accept a `self` parameter,
or are we writing top-level functions here?

---

The `flatten` helper looks good, though [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) asks
you to name the formal parameter `lst` rather than `l`.

---

The repeated applications of flatten
seem well suited to a `map( ... )` invocation,
perhaps with tuple unpack.

---

The top-level global lists are a bit of a disaster.
You have a class already.
Banish the globals by making them instance variables,
e.g. `self.zone_list`.

Also, the `_append` suffix is not great, consider eliding it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I intend to use this class with several datasets with the same structure. I will look into the map(...) invocation as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: A small cautionary note on map(). Like a bunch of other python builtins, it is a "lazy" generator. At least when you're debugging, you may want to eagerly store the results in a container: `list(map( ... ))`. The classic gotcha is `gen = map( ... ); print(gen); return gen`, which won't do what you hoped for. And if you e.g. `print(list(gen)); return gen` then the results have been used up, so none are left for the caller to retrieve. Throwing the results into a container can ease your debugging efforts a bit.